# Any idea if Spring boot is vulnerable with Ghostcat Vulnerabilty having emdeddedTomcat

Tags: spring-boot

No info in Pivotal Portal https://pivotal.io/security or https://github.com/spring-projects about CVE-2020-1938.Are they planning to fix this (if by default configuration is vulnerable) or it is up to the developer to modify the configuration ?